# Campos si/no en tabla mysql conectada a MS Access

Tags: mysql, ms-access

Tengo unas tablas creadas en mysql, que contienen algunos campos de tipo tinyint con valores 0/1.

Esta tabla la he enlazado a MS Access, pero me gustaría tratar estos campos como checkbox, o sea campos si/no de MS Access, ¿hay alguna forma para lograr esto?

Answer (score 1):

ok, creo que me faltaba probar un poco, es tan simple como agregar el check box en el formulario y asignarle de dato el campo integer, y funciona perfectamente, disculpen la molestia, estaba en un momento de poca iluminación mental